# Should I store doubles or decimals in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, numbers, decimal

When does storing doubles make sense?
Assuming you read the data off a decimal-notation CSV (e.g. with values such as "5.03"), does it make sense to use mysql's DOUBLE type? Won't there be needless round-off errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `double` numbers when you need to store really small or huge numbers. Something like `9.837262 x 10^-567`. Other than that, I'd use fixed precision numeric types to avoid the rounding errors you are mentioning.

Nowadays, I don't see "saving space" as a valid reason to use `double` instead of numeric values, but there can be some very special scenarios where this reason might be valid.

Comment: +1. In case it is useful to the OP, there is a bit of discussion here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,146172,146172#msg-146172

Comment: "saving space" will at certain point translate to saving I/O. but that is not directly proportional and it depends on the size of blocks in the filesystem and on the size (width) of the record. As long as the size of the record will not force query planner to read from extra blocks you will not perceive any performance penalty.